# Cast the content of optional or streams

Tags: java, casting, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I wish instead of writing my own method or class I could just check and cast the content of an optional to another class or have an empty object.

For this sub-problem in the application I want to have the custom user object of an instance of `TreeNode` casted to `CustomUserObject`, provided that the `TreeNode` is an instance of `DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

```
private Optional<CustomUserObject> getCustomUserObject(TreeNode node) {
    Optional<DefaultMutableTreeNode> optDefaultMutableTreeNode = OptionalUtil.cast(Optional.ofNullable(node), DefaultMutableTreeNode.class);
    Optional<Object> optUserObject = optDefaultMutableTreeNode.map(DefaultMutableTreeNode::getUserObject); //
    return OptionalUtil.cast(optUserObject, CustomUserObject.class);
}


/**
 * Maps the given optional, if the containing element is an instance of the given class.
 * Returns empty if the containing object is not an instance of the given class.
 * 
 * @param orgOptional
 *        given optional
 * @param clazz
 *        given class.
 * @return the resulting {@link Optional}.
 */
public static <T, X> Optional<T> cast(Optional<X> orgOptional, Class<T> clazz) {
    return orgOptional //
        .filter(clazz::isInstance) // check instance
        .map(clazz::cast); // cast
}

/**
 * Maps the given stream, if the containing element is an instance of the given class.
 * Returns empty if the containing object is not an instance of the given class.
 * 
 * @param orgStream
 *        given optional
 * @param clazz
 *        given class.
 * @return the resulting {@link Optional}.
 */
public static <T, X> Stream<T> cast(Stream<X> orgStream, Class<T> clazz) {
    return orgStream //
        .filter(clazz::isInstance) // check instance
        .map(clazz::cast); // cast
}
```

I remember I need to cast optionals or streams in this way quite often. It is not fluent. Actually I wish java Optional or Stream would have a cast method which does the above step. I don't want to write my own fluent CustomOptional. Did I miss anything? Is there any way to do this in a simpler way?

Comment: Aside: add `? extends` to all the type variables in method parameters, to make the API more flexible.

Comment: Write `? extends what` where? If I get you right this does not solve my problem because I need to be sure something is a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` or a `CustomUserObject`, not just declare so and wish it is one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint anyway - just: In this example `X` and `T` have no relation so `extends` does not add any value here.

Comment: but it does. The point is that by using `Class<? extends T>`, you can have an `Optional<Object>` derived from a `Optional<Serializable>`, that you cast with `String.class`. It's the sort of flexibility that costs nothing, but is really annoying if you don't have it, on the odd occasions when you need it.

Comment: Another case which might be more likely is `Optional<YourClass> opt = cast(otherOpt, instanceOfYourClass.getClass());`. As it stands, `opt` would have to be of type `Optional<? extends YourClass>`.

Comment: First of all I do not see the benefit of writing `? extends YourClass` as a result of a method because all one can do with this result is access up to `YourClass`, methods or attributes of subclasses can't be accessed with this. Secondly writing `?` has some problems and can lead to SonarLint findings.

Comment: The main benefit of writing `? extends YourClass` is that it would compile, whereas it wouldn't with just `YourClass`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to write and what does not compile?

Comment: Sure: https://ideone.com/HXaUE2. Try removing the `? extends` in `main`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But the coin does not drop for me. If you want to cast you cast to the class you want to cast to. And writing `?` for me is kind of smelly.

Comment: Ok, but why do want to cast to a dynamic class like `instance.getClass()`?

Comment: Ok, I think I got your point. So what you say is you prefer to write `public static <T, X> Optional<T> cast(Optional<X> orgOptional, Class<? extends T> clazz) ` so that it works with dynamic classes, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make this more fluent by relying on `map()`/`flatMap()` and `cast` methods that return functions instead.

For `Optional`, this is very easy since `map()` can act as a filter by returning `null`. So just define:

```
public static <U> Function<Object, U> filterAndCast(Class<? extends U> clazz) {
    return t -> clazz.isInstance(t) ? clazz.cast(t) : null;
}
```

and use it as:

```
Optional<Number> number = Optional.of(42L);
System.out.println(number.map(filterAndCast(Integer.class)));
System.out.println(number.map(filterAndCast(Long.class)));
```

Output:

```
Optional.empty
Optional[42]
```

For streams you can apply more or less the same trick by relying on `flatMap()` with a function that returns an empty `Stream`:

```
public static <U> Function<Object, Stream<U>> streamFilterAndCast(Class<? extends U> clazz) {
    return t -> clazz.isInstance(t) ? Stream.of(clazz.cast(t)) : Stream.empty();
    // or alternatively
    return t -> Stream.of(t).filter(clazz::isInstance).map(clazz::cast);
}
```

and use it as:

```
Stream.of(42L, "Hello world", 1024, 3.14)
        .flatMap(streamFilterAndCast(Number.class))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
42
1024
3.14
```

Comment: Thanks for this inspiring answer. Just as a remark the ternary operator `?` is forbidden in most projects I work because it is error prone and hard to read.

Comment: @michaeak I understand the "hard to read" part (though I think that's pure opinion), but as to the error-prone part, I think the truth is exactly the opposite.  Using an if-else has many more opportunities for error than a ternary, because the ternary is more constrained.  Also, statements must operate by side-effects, but a ternary is an expression, making it more composible.  So when you run into whoever wrote that style guide, tell them I said it was OK :)

Comment: @brian-goetz well, I had a project where there was a person using 3 or 4 composed ternaries. And also it is widely used for null checks, which is supposed to be done by `Optional`, so for me the ternary is not fine, not using it myself, even though I know how it works.

Comment: @michaeak I'm sure that was annoying, but you are making an absurd argument, essentially: "because someone abused a feature once, no one can ever use it again, even when it is the absolutely right thing."  (This is like saying "cars are not fine" because someone was once hit by a drunk driver.)  The ternary is an important tool in the language toolbox, and in many cases where it applies, is an objectively better choice than an if-then, and when used correctly, is entirely as readable.  Blame bad developers for their bad code, not the tools they choose.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this for **Optional**

```
/**
 * Creates a function that tries to cast to the given class.
 * If the given argument is not an instance of the given class <code>Optional.empty()</code> is returned.
 * This function can be used in an <code>optionalObject.flatMap(Functional.cast(SomeClass.class))</code> context.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *        given Clazz
 * @return Returns an optional of the given class.
 * @param <X>
 *        generic input argument for the function
 * @param <T>
 *        type of the output of the function
 */
public static <X, T> Function<X, Optional<T>> cast(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    return x -> {
        if (clazz.isInstance(x)) {
            return Optional.of(clazz.cast(x));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Optional<DefaultMutableTreeNode> optParent = Optional.of(node) // optional of original node
                    .map(ProfileTreeNode::getParent) // parent of this node.
                    .flatMap(FunctionalUtil.cast(DefaultMutableTreeNode.class)); // cast to DefaultMutableTreeNode
                optParent.ifPresent(y -> y.remove(node));
```

For **streams** I wrote

```
/**
 * Creates a function that tries to cast to the given class.
 * If the given argument is not an instance of the given class an empty stream is returned.
 * This function can be used in an <code>stream.flatMap(Functional.castStream(SomeClass.class))</code> context.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *        given Clazz
 * @return Returns an optional of the given class.
 * @param <X>
 *        generic input argument for the function
 * @param <T>
 *        type of the output of the function
 */
public static <X, T> Function<X, Stream<T>> castStream(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    return x -> Stream.of(x) // stream of x.
        .filter(clazz::isInstance) // check if instance
        .map(clazz::cast);
}
```